# Can you use Panels in Bootstrap 2.3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is there any easy way of using bootstrap 3 panels within bootstrap 2.3. From what I can see the panels styling is a new feature within BS 3.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For this your bootstrap.css code must have the styling of panels. So that you have to paste the below styles into your bootstrap.css/bootstrap.min.css file. If you are not interested in changing the core files, you can add it in your css files. you can follow the codes in http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels after doing this.

```
.panel {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.panel-heading {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: -15px -15px 15px;
  font-size: 17.5px;
  font-weight: 500;      
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}

.panel-footer {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 15px -15px -15px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}

.panel-primary {
  border-color: #428bca;
}

.panel-primary .panel-heading {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #428bca;
  border-color: #428bca;
}

.panel-success {
  border-color: #d6e9c6;
}

.panel-success .panel-heading {
  color: #468847;
  background-color: #dff0d8;
  border-color: #d6e9c6;
}

.panel-warning {
  border-color: #fbeed5;
}

.panel-warning .panel-heading {
  color: #c09853;
  background-color: #fcf8e3;
  border-color: #fbeed5;
}

.panel-danger {
  border-color: #eed3d7;
}

.panel-danger .panel-heading {
  color: #b94a48;
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #eed3d7;
}

.panel-info {
  border-color: #bce8f1;
}

.panel-info .panel-heading {
  color: #3a87ad;
  background-color: #d9edf7;
  border-color: #bce8f1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you plan to put a table inside the panel, you'll want to also add

```
.panel>.table, .panel>.table-responsive>.table {
      margin-bottom: 0;
}
```